# Does barometer improve gps position accuracy?

Tags: gps

It is clear that a barometer is more accurate in measuring altitude than GPS.
However is it true that the barometer improves GPS position accuracy?

Would be a GPS device and a GPS+barometer device equally accurate if we didn't look at the altitude?

Comment: "It is clear..."? You seem to have both a particularly low quality GPS device and a particularly magic barometer. What devices are you using, and what numbers do you have for their errors in altitude? GPS should be accurate to meters, barometers can be off by hundreds of meters.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Most aircraft use aneroid barometers suitably calibrated as they are more accurate than the GPS devices.   Some gps devices have an aneroid barometer built in to improve the height accuracy.  Have a look at http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14789/how-do-aircraft-altimeters-calculate-altitudes-accurately-while-airborne and http://gpstracklog.com/2012/12/all-about-barometric-altimeters.html

Comment: The best hand-held barometers I've used haven't been that good - drift over a day was pretty bad. those in airplanes are better, but not for hiking with.

Comment: @ChrisWhite The barometers are used in MobilePhones,Watches,GPSTrackers to improve accuracy of GPS. Common GPS can have altitude 20 m off. Look at for instance on [BMP280](https://ae-bst.resource.bosch.com/media/_tech/media/datasheets/BST-BME280_DS001-11.pdf)

Comment: That is just not so. You can buy GPS devices that have cm or even mm accuracy. The designers of your cell phone just didn't care about that.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Barometers have terrible absolute accuracy (because air pressure varies, obviously), but they can have rather good differential accuracy.  So if air pressure isn't varying much and you have a good zero point, barometers can be very good.

Comment: You can well improve altitude measurement with a barometer if you have a weather station on ground in the vicinity of your location. Then you can take difference between readings of the onboard barometer and the ground weather sation. But if you don't have the ground weather station, then the issue is natural weather fluctuations that are hard to avoid.

Comment: @Farcher Airplanes use barometers because they don't care about height above ground. The only thing that matters is the pressure at which they are flying. That reading is often converted to feet based on a standard atmosphere, but this is just tradition and that is certainly not an accurate measure of the number of feet between the plane and the ground. The only way to make a barometer accurate is to calibrate it (within the last couple hours, and not very far from where you are using it). That calibration is done with a GPS!

Comment: To get ~ cm's of accuracy from GPS you are talking about *differential gps*. This requires a local base station that's surveyed-in to cm's of accuracy, and permissions to communicate with it.

Comment: And the altitude gps provides is relative to the WGS standard geodetic ellipsoid. It has nothing to do with pressure. But some INS may still use pressure readings to augment their measurements.

Comment: If it helps the topic at all, the galaxy Nexus smartphone contains both a barometer and a GPS. The barometer sensor is not available for any use at all by the "normal system". It's used to input one of the variables (altitude) into the GPS calculations, to provide for a faster lock on position (that variable doesn't need to be determined from scratch). It does not, however, improve the GPS accuracy. This is only one example case I know about...

Comment: @CuriousOne: "*You can buy GPS devices that have cm or even mm accuracy*". Yes, but you won't be able to use it with this accuracy, it won't be really better than a recreational one. You won't have access to the second GPS frequency (L2) which is for US military, and some very specific civilian uses like surveying. A key is required to decode L2 frames. Also you need a local differential GPS as mentioned by *docscience*, or a carrier phase tracking system, or access to a real time kinematic (RTK) network. Precise fixes rely on corrections, longer measurement times and averaging.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: "*Airplanes use barometers because they don't care...*", you are perfectly right and you introduce facts in this discussion which seems to lack some. Just a comment, the setting of the altimeter doesn't use the GPS, the traffic control (or automated stations) just provides the current pressure on the ground at a nearby location (e.g. airfield), and you display this value in the "[Kollsman window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altimeter)".

Comment: @mins: The OP didn't say that using differential techniques and averaging weren't allowed. The commercial availability of precision devices proves beyond any doubt that the OP is flat out wrong about the precision of GPS, even without the military codes.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I wasn't commenting the OP question, but the fact that getting a high precision  [Trimble station](http://www.trimble.com/Survey/TrimbleR10.aspx?tab=GNSS_System_Comparison) doesn't provide you access to this precision unless you are a surveyor.

Comment: @mins: I was commenting the OP's question and his statement is simply not true. There is really nothing of interest to say about this topic. In any case, barometric measurements are no more precise than naive GPS, so it's a lose-lose, either way. For the hiker the solution is given by a precise altitude map, for the commercial airliner with flight approved navigation systems that are _not_ GPS based. If lives depend on it, a radio altimeter is always preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The science of [sensor fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion) provides, by the combination of multiple, seemingly redundant measurements, a reduction of variance in the combined measurement. Basically speaking, for independent, identically distributed noise processes, the signal to noise of combined $n$ measurements is increased by the factor of $\sqrt{n}$.

And in fact, commercial INS (Inertial Navigation Systems) include among the accelerometers, GPS recievers, and gyro sensors, an [aneroid barometer](http://www.britannica.com/technology/aneroid-barometer), all of which feed into a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) resulting in a very accurate estimate of position, velocity and three axis attitude.

Examples include the [LN100](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/LN100GInertialNavigationSystem/Pages/default.aspx) fom Litton and Honeywell's [EGI](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/products/navigation-and-sensors/embedded-gps-or-ins) (Embedded GPS in INS) systems

Comment: A barometric altimeter doesn't measure the altitude. If you follow the altimeter, you follow an isobaric surface, and the actual altitude may vary a lot. In cruise the altimeter is set to a standard reference pressure of 1013.25 hPa on the ground, which is likely wrong all the time, but the same for all aircraft which can use different isobaric surfaces (named flight levels) to prevent collision. There is no barometric altimeter in the INS. GPS is way more accurate than inertial systems, INS is used because it's not relying on any external equipment.

Comment: @mins it may be that with your particular experience with GPS-INS systems there was no barometer involved, but I know from my own experience and the Honeywell model we used there was a barometer in the instrument as part of the sensor fusion algorithm. Also if you just google a combination of 'GPS INS Barometer' you will find many articles that discuss the use. I don't know the exact details in the KF but suspect the barometer reading is loosely coupled; doesn't have significant weighting.

Comment: These units combine 3 instruments: INS, GPS and barometer to get the [best of 3 worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS/INS): GPS for accuracy, INS and barometer for better rates of measure. But neither INS or barometer increase GPS accuracy. This is used when high rates of measure are needed (e.g. missile guidance), which cannot be achieved with GPS alone. So between two actual GPS measures, the position **variation** is estimated using the other quicker instruments, the result has likely a lower accuracy than the GPS alone. If you have another information, please post a link.